# google cloud storage client library - behind proxy - access bucket objects using python code?

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, google-cloud-storage

Centos Linux on vmware - gsutil is working but I am trying to download objects from google cloud storage using python code. Running below python code fails as I am behind a proxy server. I tried exporting http_proxy and https_proxy, also adding it via .boto (though i'm guessing only gsutil uses it). But none works.

I can't find any mention of proxy settings in the documentation as well.

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('my-bucket')
blobs=bucket.list_blobs()
```

OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable

***UPDATE 24-JULY-17 - RESOLVED ***

> re-installed google cloud storage library and my script works fine
>   with HTTP_PROXY set in the env. Not sure about the root cause for
>   initial troubles and I was not able to reproduce the error again
>   unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Although, [`google-cloud` python library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) does not have support for proxies directly, it honors `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variable if set.

Either:

```
export HTTPS_PROXY=https://mycustomproxy.example.com:12345
python your_python_script.py
```

Or:

```
export https_proxy=https://mycustomproxy.example.com:12345
python your_python_script.py
```

You could also set this directly within your python script too (preferably at the very beginning):

```
import os
os.environ['https_proxy'] = 'https://mycustomproxy.example.com:12345'

from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket('my-bucket')
blobs=bucket.list_blobs()
```

BTW, `https_proxy` is supported in the `urllib` module and hence any libraries (like `google-cloud` here) using `urllib` can transparently use the proxies for the requests.

Comment: Thanks. I did export https_proxy and http_proxy before running the code. But I will try setting it up from within the code to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused - If that does not work, share the format you used for the proxy string. If your proxy requires authentication, you will have to include the username and password in the proxy string unfortunately. For that case, I would suggest doing it within the code dynamically so that your credentials never get saved directly anywhere.

Comment: I just pip uninstalled the library and ran pip install again and it seems to work fine using HTTP_PROXY exported in the shell !! It is a bit worrying though not knowing the reason

Answer (score 0):

The [`google-cloud` python library](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/) doesn't have support for proxies.
gsutil's proxy support comes from its use of the boto library, so you might consider using that library if you need proxy support.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use https://github.com/google/apitools and pass an httplib2 instance that is initialized with a proxy.  This is how gsutil works with proxies when using the GCS JSON API.  Code is here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/blob/adf221296d77968b8c7c4bde6dccd235664703ac/gslib/util.py#L786

Comment: @Mike - This is incorrect. the python library honors whatever proxy setting is configured in the environment. Look at my answer below.

Comment: @Tuxdude - thanks for the correction. I had looked at the google-cloud-python source when I posted that answer, and I didn't realize that lib indirectly supports proxies. Can you point me to where/how that's done? Thanks.

Comment: The official documentation for this unfortunately is very bleak. You will see mentions of http_proxy and ftp_proxy in the [urlopen doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) but nothing more than that. The release notes of urllib mentions when they added support for HTTP/HTTPS proxies, so that might help track down the code I guess.