# Python: access google cloud storage using proxy server

Tags: python, proxy, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am trying the different way to access Google cloud storage and bigquery using the proxy server where I have tried using Unix option:

```
export https_proxy=http://myproxy-server.com:myport
```

then trigger the Python code

I also specified coding it in Python like:

```
import os 
proxy = 'http://myproxy-server.com:myport'
os.environ['https_proxy'] = proxy

#[Further code goes here]
```

Both of the above options are working fine, however, I am trying to find out more option to access Google cloud using the proxy server by specifying/setting up the proxy through Python code.

Can we do it using any other option?

Comment: You can check out [this Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45173466/google-cloud-storage-client-library-behind-proxy-access-bucket-objects-using?rq=1).

Comment: Could you explain what exactly you are looking for and why those methods that you mentioned are not sufficient for you?

Comment: @komarkovich - I am looking different approach to supply proxy while connecting to Google platform. These methods are already working and I am trying to explore more options that can be used for such connection.