# How to use the Google Speech to Text API behind the Proxy settings?

Tags: ios, swift

How to use the Google Speech To Text API behind the Proxy Settings in the iOS application? When I am trying to create the connection behind the proxy I am getting "Failed to create subchannel" error. Please suggest any solution to resolve this error.

Comment: Did you get any solution? If not can you please post a sample project on git and share a link so that i can look into it

Answer (score 1):

Simply Add following line in your python code

```
import os  
os.environ["http_proxy"] = "http://<ip>:<port>"
os.environ["https_proxy"] = "https://<ip>:<port>"
```

Example: http://10.78.21.2:8082

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45179989/3302263) Google clients (among them Speech to text client) honor `http_proxy` or `https_proxy` environment variables.

Consider connecting to Google Speech to text API using Google cloud client
or peep into the code and try implementing similar proxy solution.

Here's Python client and there are clients for other languages too
https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python